# Could someone tell me how do I remove an item from the ItemsGrouped collection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In a normal colletion I would use **CollectionName.Remove(item);**

But in this colletion with `<Grouping <string, Device>` I do not understand how to do this. I need to remove the item to update my ListView.

All help is welcome, thank you!

**ViewModel:**

> **Constructor:**
>
> ```
> var sorted = from item in Devices
>                          orderby item.Grupo
>                          group item by item.Grupo.ToString() into itemGroup
>                          select new Grouping<string, Device>(itemGroup.Key, itemGroup);
>
>             ItemsGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Device>>(sorted);
> ```

```
public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices
{
    get { return _devices; }
    set
    {
        _devices = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Device>> ItemsGrouped { get; set; }




 public class Device:ViewModelBase
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Image { get; set; }
            public string Grupo { get; set; }
        }



public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
        {
            public K Key { get; private set; }

            public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
            {
                Key = key;
                foreach (var item in items)
                    this.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743420/remove-an-item-from-an-observablecollection-in-a-collectionchanged-event-handler answer can help you.

Comment: Hello my friend, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't delete the item in the grouped collection but instead in the source of the grouping.

You already have a copy of the original collection `Devices`, remove the item there and re-do the grouping.

Comment: Hello my friend, I followed your suggestion and solved the problem, thank you very much for your help!